# Gnuplot Multiple files in one Plot

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I use gnuplot for plotting data from 4 files on a single graph (png).

**I get the 4 plots as different colored lines.**

I want them to be **of different line types** so that the plot can be easily **recognized in a black and white print out**.

How to do that ? Many thanks for your help.

So what I want is http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/lines_arrows.html : Second figure. In Gnuplot, I get the plots as different colored lines.

Comment: what version of gnuplot do you use? Try to check if the terminal (pngcairo) supports dash lines by typing `set termoption dashed; test` in gnuplot (you should see a window with different objects, some of them will or not be dashed lines). Since version 5.0 you can use the option `dashtype` or `dt` to change the dash style, e.g. `plot 'data1' dt 1, 'data2' dt 2` (type `help dashtype` in gnuplot 5.0 for more info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure which detail of your question is the aspect you're struggeling with. When plotting from multiple files you specify this with `plot 'FILENAME' using COLUMNS ... , 'FILENAME2' using COLUMNS ...`

From the example you posted I see that the lines are black as long as `lt -1` stays in. If you take it out, things become colorful. `linespoints` essentially connects the dots with lines, in the example that's pulled up to `set style func linespoints` which won't work here, as it's not a function which gets plotted.

Following the example you linked I suggest this:

```
set title ""
set xlabel ""
set bmargin 6
set offset .05, .05
set xrange [-0.5:3.3]

plot 'd1' using 1:2 lt -1  pt 6 ps 2 title 'pt 6' with linespoints,\
     'd2' using 1:2 lt -1  pt 5 ps 2 title 'pt 5' with linespoints,\
     'd3' using 1:2 lt -1  pt 7 ps 2 title 'pt 7' with linespoints,\
     'd4' using 1:2 lt -1  pt 4 ps 2 title 'pt 4' with linespoints
```

where `d1` looks like:

```
-0.5  0.8775825619
-0.4  0.921060994
-0.3  0.9553364891
-0.2  0.9800665778
-0.1  0.9950041653
 0.0  1.0000000000
 0.1  0.9950041653
 0.2  0.9800665778
 0.3  0.9553364891
 0.4  0.921060994
 0.5  0.8775825619
 0.6  0.8253356149
 0.7  0.7648421873
 0.8  0.6967067093
 0.9  0.6216099683
 1.0  0.5403023059
 1.1  0.4535961214
 1.2  0.3623577545
 1.3  0.2674988286
 1.4  0.1699671429
 1.5  0.0707372017
 1.6 -0.0291995223
 1.7 -0.1288444943
 1.8 -0.2272020947
 1.9 -0.3232895669
 2.0 -0.4161468365
 2.1 -0.5048461046
 2.2 -0.5885011173
 2.3 -0.6662760213
 2.4 -0.7373937155
 2.5 -0.8011436155
 2.6 -0.8568887534
 2.7 -0.904072142
 2.8 -0.9422223407
 2.9 -0.9709581651
 3.0 -0.9899924966
 3.1 -0.9991351503
 3.2 -0.9982947758
 3.3 -0.9874797699
```

EDIT:

thanks for clarifying. A few more pointers

Colors themselves: I recommend http://colorbrewer2.org/ to pick colors which are "photocopy safe". These tend to be well distinguishable even if printed in grayscale.

Markers: with the point type e.g. `pt 5` you can specify different markers for the data. I changed the size with `ps 2` in the above example. Especially open and filled markers are easily distinguishable from each other.

Linestyle: you need version 5 of gnuplot:

> New features in version 5
>   * The dot-dash pattern of a line can now be specified independent of other
>   line properties. See dashtype
>   (p. 37), set dashtype (p. 115), set linetype (p. 135).

Without upgrading I couldn't get this to run, which is derived from the page you linked:

```
set termoption dash
unset colorbox
set title ""
set xlabel ""
set bmargin 6
set offset .05, .05
set xrange [-0.5:3.3]
show style line

plot 'd2' using 1:2 with linespoints dt 2 lw 3 lc rgb "black" ps -1,\
   'd3' using 1:2 with linespoints dt 1      lc rgb "black" ps -1,\
   'd4' using 1:2 with linespoints dt 3      lc rgb "black" ps -1
```

here `dt` is short for dash type, `lw` is line width, `lc` is line color which i set to black, `ps` is point style, disabled, so we don't see the points but only lines

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to ask (not specific to the link) How to generate a plot in gnuplot with multiple lines so that even in black and white paper it can be easily recognized. I don't have the repo to post images. Like : 1. x 2. y 3. z all vs. t. When I plot uthem using gnuplot .. in the same graph --- I should get one of them as dotted one of them as straight one of them like bars --- so that all can be distinguished.